# como fazer item selecionado da tabela dinâmica mudar de cor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá! estou com um projeto básico de JavaScript e HTML, do qual a pessoa irá adicionar dados à a tabela(ela será feita pelo próprio usuário e até ai tudo bem(Consegui implementar até o botão de excluir). Porém, quando a pessoa seleciona, um dos itens da lista para excluir, simplesmente não dá para saber justamente porque a cor do mesmo não muda.

```js
let pessoas, index;

function inserir(item,descricao,quantidade,valor) {
    pessoas = document.getElementById("tabela");
    var qtdlLinhas = pessoas.rows.length;
    var linha = pessoas.insertRow(qtdlLinhas);
    var linhaParam;
    

    var cellItem = linha.insertCell(0);
    var cellDesc = linha.insertCell(1);
    var cellQuantidade = linha.insertCell(2);
    var cellValor = linha.insertCell(3);

    cellItem.innerHTML = item;
    cellDesc.innerHTML = descricao;
    cellQuantidade.innerHTML = quantidade;
    cellValor.innerHTML = valor;

    preencheCamposForm();

}

function preencheCamposForm() {

    for (var i = 0; i < pessoas.rows.length; i++) {
        pessoas.rows[i].onclick = function () {
            index = this.rowIndex;
            document.getElementById("txtItem").value = pessoas.rows[index].cells[0].innerText;
            document.getElementById("txtDesc").value = pessoas.rows[index].cells[1].innerText;
            document.getElementById("txtQuantidade").value = pessoas.rows[index].cells[2].innerText;
            document.getElementById("txtValor").value = pessoas.rows[index].cells[3].innerText;
        }
    }
}

function delRegistro() {
    

    for (var i = 0; i < pessoas.rows.length; i++) {
        if (index == i) {
            pessoas.deleteRow(index);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.459);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande",
    "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}
select {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: ;
}

form {
  background-color: #0000005e;
}

.form-group {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.form-control {
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  padding: 10px;
}
.form-control1 {
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  padding: 10px;
}
textarea {
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  padding: 10px;
}

label {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.btn {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.table {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Modelador de orçamentos</title>
    <script typeof="text/javascript" src="back.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="visual.css">
</head>
<header>
    <h1>Modelador de orçamentos</h1>
</header>

<body>
  <main>
         <form>
            <!--FORMULÁRIO-->
                <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="txtItem">Item</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="txtItem" placeholder="Item">
             </div>
             <label for="txtDesc">Descrição:</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDesc" placeholder="Descrição">
    </div>
    <div class="second-line">
         <div class="form-group">
              <label for="txtQuantidade">Quantidade:</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtQuantidade" placeholder="Quantidade">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
              <label for="txtValor">Valor</label>
             <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtValor" placeholder="Valor">
         </div>
    </div>
    <!--BOTÕES-->
    <div class="buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
            onclick="inserir(txtItem.value, txtDesc.value, txtQuantidade.value, txtValor.value)">
            Inserir
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="delRegistro()">
            Excluir
        </button>
    </div>
    </form>
    </main>
    <table id="tabela" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Item</th>
            <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantidade</th>
            <th scope="col">Valor</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) cria uma classe css com a cor alterada, por exemplo `.selecionado { background-color: cyan }` 2) adiciona um evento "click" na nova linha da tabela, 3) na função do evento click use o método `toggle` para adicionar/remover a classe, por exemplo `.... function(tr) { tr.classList.toggle('selecionado'); }`

Comment: Infelizmente também não funcionou essa solução

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma que consegui alterando o seu código seria:

```js
let tabela, index;

function inserir(item, descricao, quantidade, valor) {
    tabela = document.getElementById("tabela");
    var qtdlLinhas = tabela.rows.length;
    var linha = tabela.insertRow(qtdlLinhas);
    var linhaParam;


    var cellItem = linha.insertCell(0);
    var cellDesc = linha.insertCell(1);
    var cellQuantidade = linha.insertCell(2);
    var cellValor = linha.insertCell(3);

    cellItem.innerHTML = item;
    cellDesc.innerHTML = descricao;
    cellQuantidade.innerHTML = quantidade;
    cellValor.innerHTML = valor;

    preencheCamposForm();

}

function preencheCamposForm() {

    for (var i = 0; i < tabela.rows.length; i++) {
        tabela.rows[i].onclick = function () {
            index = this.rowIndex;
            document.getElementById("txtItem").value = tabela.rows[index].cells[0].innerText;
            document.getElementById("txtDesc").value = tabela.rows[index].cells[1].innerText;
            document.getElementById("txtQuantidade").value = tabela.rows[index].cells[2].innerText;
            document.getElementById("txtValor").value = tabela.rows[index].cells[3].innerText;
        }
        //Início do código alterado
        tabela.rows[i].onclick = function (){this.classList.toggle("mystyle")}
        //Fim do código alterado
    }
}

function delRegistro() {


    for (var i = 0; i < tabela.rows.length; i++) {
        if (index == i) {
            tabela.deleteRow(index);
            return;
        }
    }
}


/* // DAQUI PRA BAIXO É CÓDIGO TESTE
function myFunction(element) {
    element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
 } */
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.459);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande",
    "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}
select {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: ;
}

form {
  background-color: #0000005e;
}

.form-group {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.form-control {
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  padding: 10px;
}
.form-control1 {
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  padding: 10px;
}
textarea {
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  padding: 10px;
}

label {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.btn {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

/*.table {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 300px;
}

#tabela thead th {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;

  padding: 5px 10px;
}*/

/*DAQUI PRA BAIXO É TESTE*/

.mystyle {
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Modelador de orçamentos</title>
    <script typeof="text/javascript" src="back.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="visual.css">
</head>
<header>
    <h1>Modelador de orçamentos</h1>
</header>

<body>
    <main>
        <form>
            <!--FORMULÁRIO-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtItem">Item</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="txtItem" placeholder="Item">
            </div>
            <label for="txtDesc">Descrição:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDesc" placeholder="Descrição">
            </div>
            <div class="second-line">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtQuantidade">Quantidade:</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtQuantidade" placeholder="Quantidade">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtValor">Valor</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtValor" placeholder="Valor">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--BOTÕES-->
            <div class="buttons">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                    onclick="inserir(txtItem.value, txtDesc.value, txtQuantidade.value, txtValor.value)">
                    Inserir
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="delRegistro()">
                    Excluir
                </button>
            </div>
            <p><a href="impressao.html">W3C</a></p>
        </form>
    </main>
    <table id="tabela" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <th scope="col">Item</th>
                <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
                <th scope="col">Quantidade</th>
                <th scope="col">Valor</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Fiz uma alteração para a função rodar após a renderização dentro da função **preencheCamposForm()**

Após renderizar, é referenciado o próprio elemento dentro da função onde é atribuído o evento toggle referente a classe "mystyle".

```
tabela.rows[i].onclick = function (){this.classList.toggle("mystyle")}
```

Comment: Desculpa a demora para dar um retorno, é porque eu estava tentando corrigir um bug que apareceu com isso kkkk, o excluir parou de funcionar.

Comment: Conseguiu solucionar a questão da marcação e o bug?

Answer (score -1):

No exemplo abaixo existe a classe:

```
.mystyle {
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
}
```

E você ativa e desativa através evento **toggle**

```
function myFunction(element) {
   element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}
```

É importante que na tag tr passe a função com o parâmetro **this** para a função referenciar o próprio elemento que está sendo clicado

```
<tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
<td>Conteúdo</td>
</tr>
```

```js
function myFunction(element) {
   element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}
```

```css
.mystyle {
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O ponto é que na tela HTML assim realmente funciona, porém no tipo do código que mandei, infelizmente, não. 
Mesmo adicionando os parametros que você sugeriu e removendo os meus, esse click responsivo não acontece.
link: https://jsfiddle.net/brunorafael_l/96nhecd4/

Comment: Aqui está o link com a alteração para ficar mais fácil de ver o código pela jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gutobr9/so42wgt0/1/